# Factory girl: create an object with an association to an existing object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, factory-bot

I'd like to create two objects that refer to another, single object that I've created in the before(:each) block

eg.

```
# in my factories.rb file..
factory :blah_1 do
  association :foo, :factory => :foo
end

...

# in my spec..

before(:each) do
  foo = Factory(:foo)
end

...

foo.blahs << Factory(:blah_1)
foo.blahs << Factory(:blah_1)
# some test on foo to make sure the right thing happened
```

When I run this spec it tries to create an instance of foo for both blah_1 and blah_2, failing because I don't allow a duplicate attribute.

I'd *like* to get both blah_1 and blah_2 to *reference* a single foo factory.

Thanks in advance for your help :)

Comment: did you intend the last statement in your code to say `:blah_2` instead of `:blah_1`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I ended up doing that fixed me (**please let me know if this is bad form!**)..

```
# in my factories.rb..
factory :blah_1 do
  # attributes, no associations
end

# in my spec..
before(:each) do 
  @foo = Factory(:foo)
end

...

foo.blahs << Factory(:blah_1, :foo => @foo)
foo.blahs << Factory(:blah_2, :foo => @foo)
```

It seems pretty reasonable from my perspective..

Comment: Yes, this is my final solution.